# List comprehension in Python to solve below problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Make a list comprehension to return a list of numbers which are not present in another list of numbers.

Define a list of numbers alist from 1 to 50 using a list comprehension.

Define another list blist and store its values as

```
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47]
```

Make a list final using list comprehension which would contain elements which are in alist but not in blist.

Print final

```
alist = [x for x in range(1,51)]
blist = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47]
final = [i for i in range (len(alist)) if i not in blist ]
print (final)
```

Comment: I think i am missing something with comprehension applied to either of list

Comment: What is your question here ?

Comment: Objective is to obtain following - Make a list **final** using list comprehension which would contain elements which are in **alist** but not in **blist**.

Comment: Could use set and decrease the bigger list from the smaller. Like in my answer:

Comment: @sshashank124, Thanks for your quick response, but i am not sure as how only modifying **[i for i in range (len(alist)) if i not in blist ]** to **[i for i in alist if i not in blist ]** got the answer. I mean, **range** gets the complete list items right

Comment: `range(len(...))` only gets the indices of the elements not the actual elements. Please accept the duplicate vote if your problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

You could use set() for this which would clean the duplicates in this case:

```py
alist = [x for x in range(1,51)]
blist = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47]
final = set(alist) - set(blist)
print (list(final))
```

## OUTPUT:

```
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50]
```